# Adding Dynamic Buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am kind of new to JScript... I am trying to dynamically add textboxes and select menus to a form that I have... and I have succeeded in making them appear. The problem is that the JQuery doesnt work on the form page. I can see the textboxes on the page but if I view the source they aren't there. I haven't gotten this far, but I think I may have problems when submitting the form and getting the values on another page as well. Thanks in advance
HTML:

```
<div name="Add_Interface_" id="Add_Interface_" style="display:none" class="addInt">
Add Interface 
<input type="button" name="Add_Interface_Button"id="Add_Interface_Button" value="+" onclick="addInt(this)">
</div>
```

JQUERY/Jscript

```
var counter2 = 1;
```

function addInt(button) {

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: 'dynamicButtons.php',
type: 'post',
data: {'calladdInt': '1',
'counter2': counter2}
}).done(function(response) {
  alert(response);
  var txtbox = response;
  $(button).parents().find('.addInt').append(txtbox);
});

counter2++;
}


 $('select[name=Int_Type_1]').change(function(){
   if ($('select[name=Int_Type_1]').val() == 'Switchport'){
    $('#Switchport_Div_1').show();
   }else{
    $('#Switchport_Div_1').show();
   }
  });
```

Myphp:

```
function addInt($counter2) {
$Int = array("select" => "Interface_Type_".$counter2, "dropdown" =>"Int_Client_Port_".$counter2, "dropdown2" => "Int_Server_Port_".$counter2, "dropdown3" => "Int_Uplink_".$counter2, "textbox" => "Int_Desc_" .$counter2, "select2" => "Int_Type_" .$counter2, 
"dropdown4" => "Switchport_" .$counter2, "dropdown5" => "Routed_Port_" .$counter2, "textbox2" => "Switchport_VLAN" .$counter2, "textbox3" => "IP_Routed_Port");
$Values = array("radio" => "Routable", "radio2" => "Not Routable", "dropdown" => "Client Port", "dropdown2" => "Server Port",
"dropdown3" => "Uplink", "dropdown4" => "Switchport", "dropdown5" => "Routed Port");

$addInterface = new Templates($Int, $Values);

$addInt = "<div name='Add_Interface_Type_" .$counter2. "' style=''> Interface type: ";
$addInt .= $addInterface->select. "<option>--Please Select--</option>";
$addInt .= $addInterface->dropdown. " Client Port </option>";
$addInt .= $addInterface->dropdown2. " Server Port </option>";
$addInt .= $addInterface->dropdown3.  " Uplink </option> </select>";
$addInt .= "<br> Description:" .$addInterface->textbox. "<br>";
$addInt .= $addInterface->select2. "<option>--Please Select--</option>";
$addInt .= $addInterface->dropdown4. "Switchport </option>";
$addInt .= $addInterface->dropdown5. "Routed Port </option> </select>";
$addInt .= "<div name='Switchport_Div_" .$counter2. "' style='display:none'> VLAN: " .$addInterface->textbox2;
$addInt .= "</div> <br><div name='Routed_Port_Div_".$counter2."' style='display:none'> IP Address:";
$addInt .= $addInterface->textbox3. "</div> </div>";

    return $addInt;

 }

if ($_POST['calladdInt'] == "1") {
echo addInt($_POST['counter2']);
}'
```

the part missing is my template class written in php. It just constructs the html tags and all of that is working..I can post it if anyone needs it...

Comment: Are you saying the problem is that you don't see the textboxes when you click "view page source"? Because yeah, you aren't going to, the jQuery doesn't modify the source file. You should still be able to submit the form.

Comment: I am saying I cant see the html textbox code when I view the source, but my real issue is that the jquery I wrote to show hide the textbox's at the bottom aren't working. & I am not sure if thats because the I cannot see it when I view page source?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, there's nothing wrong with your code.

From what you say, the text boxes appear on the 'rendered' HTML page, even though they are not present in the HTML source. That is because the HTML page from the response is altered and your text boxes are added. Hence, they would not be present in the original source.

Also, your observation about having problems in submitting is correct. I am no PHP-expert, but if it involves something like accessing a textbox value in the PHP code by name and getter-setter logic, that would not work.

EDIT: Any jQuery code appended as HTML in the elements of the page will not be executed. Such code should be maintained outside the elements.

Notice that your selector for the 'dynamic' box is incorrect. Your selector is for select[name=Int_Type_1] only. Hence, it would not work for others, such as select[name=Int_Type_2], which would be generated later. Use a class selector instead.

Comment: Ok, not sure I followed that 100%. On your first suggestion, are you saying after the response and the textboxes being added to my html page, I should store each one in a variable to pass along when the form submits? Will this fix the issue I am having using additional JQuery to hide and show additional boxes based on user selection to the response?

Comment: As far as form submit is concerned, yes, you have to "store the value of each text box in a variable and then pass them all along when the form submits". 

Your jQuery code to hide and show additional boxes is erroneous. The selector used is hard-coded to only the first box. When the second box is created, this selector would not work for that. Use a class selector and access the desired element and show/hide it accordingly.

Comment: Yes I know that the selector isn't going to be correct for any other select name, other than the first which is called "Int_Type_1". I was just testing the jquery first to see if I could get it to work. Thanks for your help, I suppose I will just rewrite my php function in jscript on the same html page where I make the function call from the + button click

Comment: Good luck. Hope it helped clarify something. Update the question in case you need any more help. :)